# using custom model fo django djoser

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, djoser

i am creating api endpoints for user management using Djoser and i want to use a custom model to create user and login i only want to use email.

the user entity given to me does not have a username field

below i will share the various settings i have set up for my apps

```
#accounts/model.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My serializer file

```
#accounts/serializers.py
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.fields import CurrentUserDefault
from .models import CustomUser

class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

```
#settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    )
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        # 'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.CurrentUserSerializer'
    }
```

when i try to register user i get

```
TypeError at /auth/users/

create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/
Django Version:     3.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Exception Location:     /home/femiir/.virtualenvs/codegarage/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djoser/serializers.py, line 73, in perform_create
Python Executable:  /home/femiir/.virtualenvs/codegarage/bin/python
Python Version:     3.8.5
```

please what i my doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a custom user manager, probably something like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, first name,
        last name and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            **extra_fields,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, first name,
        last name and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            **extra_fields,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

And in your custom user model:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    # [...]
    objects = MyUserManager()
    # [...]
```

I've taken the code from the django documentation about customizing the User model. They provide [an example using the email as the username field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) (which is what you want).

You may keep the inheritance from `AbstractUser` but if you do not need most of the things that are in that model, you can also inherit your model from `AbstractBaseUser`, as in the example.

Comment: Thank you so much...I have not used Based user and I don't want to start typing all field I only want email and no username field